# LazyVim: require('which-key') inside custom configuration files gives error

Tags: neovim, lua, lazyvim

I use Neovim with LazyVim configuration setup.

I want to set the mappings in `which-key`. So I put the following code inside `~/.config/nvim/lua/config/which-key.lua`:

```
local wk = require("which-key")
```

This gives the following error:

```
/Users/mertnuhoglu/.config/nvim/lua/config/which-key.lua:1174: module 'which-key' not found:
    no field package.preload['which-key']
cache_loader: module which-key not found
```

LazyVim installs and setups `which-key.nvim` by default using the following code inside `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LazyVim/lua/lazyvim/plugins/editor.lua`:

```
  {
    "folke/which-key.nvim",
    event = "VeryLazy",
        ...
  }
```

I thought maybe the error above is due to this plugin being loaded lazily. So, I did this:

```
    -- event = "VeryLazy",
        lazy = false,
```

Still, Neovim gives the same error as above.

LazyVim's documentation suggests to use the following style to customize keymaps as in https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim/blob/main/lua/lazyvim/config/keymaps.lua

```
map("n", "<leader>fn", "<cmd>enew<cr>", { desc = "New File" })
...
```

But this style is much more verbose and difficult to manage than lua tables. Therefore, I prefer to use lua tables as it is commonly used in which-key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the following code into `lua/config/keymaps.lua` file instead of `init.lua`:

```
require("config/which-key")
```

Inside `lua/config/which-key.lua` I can require `which-key` and define the mappings as usual with `which-key`.

```
local wk = require("which-key")
wk.register(mappings, opts)
```

Now, `which-key` is loaded without any errors.